# Can't Login to OrientDB Databse because of parameter conflict

Tags: database

I have a OrientDB Server Version 2.1.5 running on my local Windows 10 64Bit PC.
And on it a Database called "Metriken".
Everything worked fine and I logged in via Studio (Webbrowser).
But since today I get the "Wrong password" message while I'm entering the correct one.
In the Server Console prompts after every login the following Error_Message:

```
--> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSchemaException: Cannot add base class 'Testcase', because of parameter conflict: ObjectID (type=STRING) vs ObjectID (type=STRING) [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
```

But I have not changed anything since yesterday. But yesterday everything worked well.

I tried to start the Server as Admin and I tried to set up a new Server an copy the Database. Both didn't help.

I hope someone of you can help me, because this Database is kinda important.

Thank you!

Please excuse my bad English, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Are there other errors or warnings in the server logs?

Comment: No nothing else